# Skip Python tests if app version is less than 1.5.5

Tags: python, testing

I've got a test class with 25 tests. There are 12 tests that I only want to run if my application version is greater than 1.5.5.

I think I could add an `if` to each affected test to check the version is greater than 1.5.5. something like this:

```py
def test_to_skip(self):
    if StrictVersion(app_version) > StrictVersion('1.5.5'):
        self.skipTest('skipped test as feature is not available in this version')
    else:
        execute_test
```

This would create a lot of code duplication.

Is there any better way to do this so I can avoid the duplication?

Comment: You could probably add a version check within whatever runs your tests. However, the answer would depend a lot on how the tests are run, so you should add that information. For instance, with the vanilla `unittest`, you could put the if-then on the test suite creation, but AFAICT that would not allow easy automated test discovery.

Comment: If the code for the feature is not available, why is the test for this feature available? I see a simple solution: if there is not code for a feature, the test should not exist. But I guess I am missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a custom decorator like:

```
def skipIfAppVersionIsLowerThan(expected_version):
  if StrictVersion(app_version) < StrictVersion(expected_version):
    return unittest.skip(f'App version is lower than {expected_version}') 
  return lambda func: func
```

and then:

1. either decorate individual tests or
2. put the 1.5.5 tests in a separate test case and decorate the whole class

Example:

```
@skipIfAppVersionIsLowerThan('1.5.5')
def test1(self):
  pass
```

---

"Test skipping" docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#skipping-tests-and-expected-failures

Comment: By the way, this might not be the best solution to the underlying problem. It's just a direct answer to the question asked.

Comment: Agreed. This is not the ideal solution but the most suitable given the current setup.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Version Control, like git, then you can have 2 branches for your 2 concurrent code bases.

Your **Master** branch would be the latest version and your **pre-v1.5.5** branch would be your older version.

That way, your latest code only contains your latest tests that are applicable. The "older" test stay on your other branch.

Comment: While that could be a solution in certain cases, I infer from OP's post that they want to check application version at test time (which is entirely reasonable, and not feasible by that solution).

Comment: @Leporello That only makes sense, though, if the version is something you can configure at run-time, which in itself doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Even if an application's previous version is "frozen" (released or whatever), one might want to apply tests that were developed later. The most obvious use is regression documentation (you need to write a test that passes in version X but not in version X+1 to demonstrate that something is broken in X+1, but if that test was already part of version X you would have caught the problem before releasing X+1).